# Meteor.methods fails on the server side

Tags: mongodb, cordova, meteor, apple-push-notifications

My goal is to insert device token into db. The method succeeds on the client but fails on the server side. I have no idea why.

**// lib/meteor_methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  savePushTokens: function(myToken) {
    console.log("Saving the token.")
    Tokens.insert({token: myToken}, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    console.log("Token is now saved!");
  }
})
```

**// client/push_notifications.js**

```
...
function tokenSuccessHandler(result) {
  console.log('token success result ' + result);
  window.localStorage.setItem('deviceToken', result);
  // API call to store token on your DB
  Meteor.call('savePushTokens', result)
  console.log(Tokens.find().fetch());
}
...
```

Please see the whole file: https://github.com/mvaisanen/SimplePushApp/blob/pushplugin/client/push_notifications.js

**Xcode console output**

```
2015-01-22 10:27:51.165 myapp[33366:5680153] token success result 
077f2ea72eb6b2dfc381ce27f2eb12e2ee8ee68f7eeb90f7f2f10f1d99cd140e
2015-01-22 10:27:51.166 myapp[33366:5680153] Saving the token.
2015-01-22 10:27:51.166 myapp[33366:5680153] zp6vkrN5M4HtKF9NF
2015-01-22 10:27:51.166 myapp[33366:5680153] Token is now saved!
2015-01-22 10:27:51.166 myapp[33366:5680153] [{"token":"077f2ea72eb6b2dfc381ce27f2eb12e2ee8ee68f7eeb90f7f2f10f1d99cd140e","_id":"zp6vkrN5M4HtKF9NF"}]
```

Everything seems fine.

However, if I query database inside meteor shell, client or server, the result is empty collection. (`> Tokens.find().fetch()
[]`).

If I run the method on the server side, it actually never runs. See below.

**// lib/meteor_methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    savePushTokens: function(myToken) {
        console.log("Saving the token.")
        if (Meteor.isServer) {
                Tokens.insert({token: myToken}, function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
            console.log("Token is now saved!");
        }
    }
});
```

**Xcode console output**

```
2015-01-22 10:32:59.290 myapp[33375:5681416] token success result 077f2ea72eb6b2dfc381ce27f2eb12e2ee8ee68f7eeb90f7f2f10f1d99cd140e
2015-01-22 10:32:59.291 myapp[33375:5681416] Saving the token.
2015-01-22 10:32:59.291 myapp[33375:5681416] []
```

Any idea? The full repo is here https://github.com/mvaisanen/SimplePushApp/tree/pushplugin

**UPDATE**

I have `autopublish` and `insecure` installed.

I start the app with `meteor run ios-device --mobile-server 192.168.1.6:3000`.

I can manually insert data to db via meteor shell or meteor mongo.

I have also tried to check for tokens in `meteor mongo`:

```
$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12                 
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
meteor:PRIMARY> db.tokens.find();
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

But I get no tokens.

**UPDATE 2**

I haven't been able to fix the bug. Is there any simple (or complex) Meteor apps on github (or somewhere else) which have Apple push notifications and which I could clone and thus find the solutions.

Comment: Basic question... do you have 'insecure' and 'autopublish' packages installed/removed? If they are removed you need to publish and subscribe to data and have write access to the collection. Right now you are successfully writing to the client minimongo.

Comment: Both 'insecure' and 'autopublish' are installed. I have really basic app with push notifications. I am only testing whether I can get the push notifications working.

Comment: do you have `aldeed:simpleschema` or `aldeed:collection2` installed?

Comment: @richsilv, nope. Never heard of it actually.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite likely that the token *is* saving but the way you're looking at it makes it appear as if its not, because it may not be visible at the places you're looking at the instant its being looked at.

Keep in mind that :

- Meteor doesn't publish all data to the client unless `autopublish` is in to your project.
- If you insert something on the server, it is not immediately available on the client, in the case that it is published to the client

The way that you look for the tokens is right after you call `Meteor.call`, it's not very likely the data would have been received on the client at this point.

I'm not sure whether this would make any difference, but you're using asynchronous javascript on the server. Meteor uses fibers and you don't have to do this.

It's helpful in that, if there is a problem meteor will throw an error. You can simply do this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Tokens.insert({token: myToken});
    console.log("Token is now saved!");
}
```

To check whether the token has been inserted, the best way is to use the `meteor mongo` console while your app is running and check whether the tokens are in there, this is the actual mongo shell to the database so meteor's publish delay/lack of publish method is likely not to be an issue.

```
meteor mongo
>db.tokens.find();
```

(If your collection is called 'tokens', ie : `var PushTokens = new Mongo.Collection("tokens")`.

Comment: If I check for tokens in meteor mongo, it returns nothing. Is lib folder right place to put methods? Should I use Meteor.isServer with methods or not? Neither way works at the moment.